# Transforming the string representation of a dictionary into a real dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, numpy

I am working on an image processing script. I need to let the user specify how to remap some classes in an image via a text file. The syntax in this file should be simple and self-evident. What I thought of doing is to get the user to write the string version of a dictionary:

```
125:126, 126:126, 127:128, 128:128
```

and then transform it into a real dictionary (this is the missing link):

```
a = {125:126, 126:126, 127:128, 128:128}
```

The remapping of the classes of the image would then be done like this:

```
u, indices = numpy.unique(image, return_inverse=True)
for i in range(0, len(u)):
    u[i] = a[u[i]]
updatedimage = u[indices]
updatedimage = numpy.resize(updatedimage, (height, width)) #Resize to original dims
```

Is there a simple way to do this transformation from the "string version" to a real dictionary? Can you think of an easier/alternative one-line syntax that the user could use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('{' + s + '}')
{128: 128, 125: 126, 126: 126, 127: 128}
```

Note that this requires Python 2.6 or newer.

An alternative is to split the string on `','` and then split each piece on `':'` and construct a `dict` from that:

```
>>> dict(map(int, x.split(':')) for x in s.split(','))
{128: 128, 125: 126, 126: 126, 127: 128}
```

Both examples assume that your initial string is in a variable called `s`:

```
>>> s = '125:126, 126:126, 127:128, 128:128'
```

Comment: Thanks, both work great. I prefer your alternative; it will save another import, and work with older version...